# post form to different page then return

Tags: php, forms, redirect

My form on **the-form-page.php** gets POST'd on submit to **handlerpage.php**.

After the POST I need to redirect back to **the-form-page.php**.

Well that is absolutely no problem and is currently working.   User fills out the form on **the-form-page.php**, presses 'submit', POST data is handled by **handlerpage.php** (some calculations and writing results to mysql database), then I successfully redirect back to **the-form-page.php** using window.location=

The problem is there is large data created on **handlerpage.php** from data submitted in the POST of **the-form-page.php** that needs to come back to **the-form-page.php** AND the original form data needs to come back to **the-form-page.php** also so the user sees 'Ah, there's my original data and there's the results.'

I can't use GET to programmatically return to **the-form-page.php** -- data too big for GET params.
And I'd like to stick with window.location= as the redirection method (if possible).

How can I redirect back to **the-form-page.php** and display the user's original data with the results of the processing from **handlerpage.php**?

NOTE: re-architecting so that **the-form-page.php** and **handlerpage.php** are combined is NOT an option.

And I'm already partway there, after processing the data on **handlerpage.php** I'm successfully returning now to **the-form-page.php**, I just need to re-populate it with the original data and the new data created on **handlerpage.php**.

Comment: For redirection, use *headers*. For getting form data back, use *sessions*.

Comment: The problem with header() is as soon as the first 'echo' or any other type of browser output occurs, you can no longer user header() without getting the 'header already sent' error.  window.location avoids it.

Comment: You can use output buffering, or, handle the message outside the redirection part.

Answer (score 1):

How about [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)? Here is a [simple example](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm). In your **the-form-page.php** check session varible's value and populate. You can set sesions variables in **handlerpage.php**.

Comment: I'm using sessions.  What I don't like is this.  When the user closes the browser the session data is still there.  For example, developing on my localhost machine, I can close the browser, and come back the next day, and navigate to the site, and I find that my user login in the session is still there!  I don't even have to login again, I'm still logged in from yesterday!  If I could terminate the session on 'last browser window' closed by the user, I'd feel better about sessions. Using a timeout seems REAL kludgy for the data that might still be in the Session for a while.

Comment: Session should be cleared as soon as the browser window is closed. Are you talking about your browser saving your form data? This has nothing to do with PHP and its your browser doing that for you. You have to disable it or choose not to remeber data when asked.

Comment: When you close the browser the session data is destroyed, so what you are saying is not true.
Unless you are just closing the tab.
There are ways around it though, by checking last activity time+date.

Comment: While logged in, the userid is saved in the session so the server can discern which user is the 'logged in user' to ensure correct database access and to display "You are currently logged in as " . loggedInUserName (from my session variable).  I can then close all browser windows while still logged in.  I can open a new browser window on my localhost machine the next day, and still see "You are currently logged in as " . loggedInUserName  from the session variable.

Comment: @Erik actually this *is* precisely what's happening.  I have personally read posts on SO that mention the session doesn't go away immediately.  Just enter 'session not destroyed' in SO's search and you'll read posts like stackoverflow.com/questions/3043651/logout-problem-session-not-destroyed

Comment: Are you using cookie or session? Because session gets destroyed after closing the browser. Its not possible what you are mentioning unless some cookie is specified.

Comment: As I mention above -- have a read of stackoverflow.com/questions/3043651/logout-problem-session-not-destroyed.   Then to prove to yourself that the session does NOT go away 'when the last browser window is closed' -- do this:  type "session not destroyed" at the top right of this Stack Overflow window and start reading.  I am in fact using SESSION in php and have been doing so for a while now and am pretty used to this issue with the session not going away.

Comment: I am sure there will be some edge cases where sessions do not get destroyed, to prevent this add a date+time value to your session that registers the user's last action.
On the next action check how long it has been since the last action and set a timeout.

Comment: @Erik right I'm aware of the timeout strategy.  As I mentioned above I find it kludgy for its 'indirectiveness' nature, I find it slipshod, scattershot and instills a compulsory limit on idleness of the user login time.  Scattershot, kludgy and inelegant and distasteful and ridiculous harebrained shoddy cr?ap.  Nevertheless I understand the underpinnings of it.  Just hair-raising painful stuff.  Reminds me of the days when you paid by the minute for Internet access and your login session would timeout at the worst times.

Comment: Just to clarify -- I'm seeing this 'persistent session' when: (1) I'm logged in and my user Id is stored in the session;  (2) without logging out, I close the browser window and no other browser windows are open;  (3) and furthermore, my php.ini file, the only one on my machine, has this statement: session.cookie_lifetime = 0 (4) and yet I can come back several hours later, navigate to localhost/mysite, and the landing page is still able to find my userid in a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to invent your own [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), only without **A** (and also **JA** and **X**) in it.

I'd suggest you to submit form using AJAX, to return JSON-encoded "new data" on **handlerpage.php** and then to display the received content back on **the-form-page.php**.